# Looking for a ZAPIER solution - mapping inbound comma delimited text value to codes held in Google Sheet

Tags: zapier

We have a ZAP which is triggered on submission of a Zoho Form.

One of the fields passed into the ZAP from the ZohoForm is a text field containing one or more comma delimited strings

for example
String one, String two, string three, string four

The ZAP needs to;
1. Break this text into its component parts given by the comma delimiter
ie
String one
String two
String three
String four

2. For each individual item from (1) above, perform a lookup in a specific google sheet to map the string value to a code given in the sheet, where the sheet is of the form
   Col A = lookup value
   Col B = code

ie
String one    001
String two    092
String three  011
etc

3. For each match return the associated code (given by Col B) and for each failed match return a value 999999
4. Re-form a single comma delimited string from the results in step 3,
   ie 
   001, 092, 011, 999999

So, we can use ZAPIER's Split Text Formatter for step 1 above, returning either "line items" or "separate fields" but there doesn't appear to be a native function to iterate through these to find the match in a Google Sheet.

ZAPIER product support say we need a Custom Javascript function.

Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Zapier product support in that you are going to need to use Zapier's code module which allows you to program in either Python or Javascript.

The way you are formatting your data may need to change, as well it is unclear what you intend to do with the data after it is returned presumably its recorded somewhere else.

**Here is a template for what the architecture of this might look like:**

To iteratively pass lookup values to the google spreadsheet lookup Zap you're going to need to setup up two separate zaps and be somewhat familiar with either Python or Javascript.

The first Zap will contain a trigger and action step. The trigger will be "on new form created in Zoho" the action step will be either a Python code module or a Javascript module, whichever you prefer. In the action step you will need to place the text field string into the input_data dictionary. Your code might look like as follows (I have written this in Python as that is what I am familiar with, but the same thing can be achieved in Javascript):

```
lookup_values = input_data.get("text_field")
lookup_values = lookup_values.split(",")
for value in lookup_values:
    requests.post(url="zapier_webhook.com", json={"lookup": value})
```

You will notice the:

```
requests.post(url="zapier.webhook.com", json=value)
```

This is a method for sending and receiving http requests. In this case I am sending (requests.post) the json data (json=value) to an endpoint url (url="zapier.webhook.com"). The url I have specified is just a place holder, you will need to setup the second Zap to get the actual endpoint url. That will be everything for the first Zap.

The second Zap will have at least two zaps, a trigger and an action. You may need to add additional action steps depending on what you want to do with your data, but this is a good place to start. The trigger will be using the "catch hook" trigger of the Zapier webhook module. When you set this up Zapier will provide you with an endpoint url that you can send data to. You will need to replace the place holder url from the first zap with this url. The data this endpoint is going to receive is going to be the individual strings sent to it from the action step of the first Zap. After setting up the trigger you can setup the action step which is going to be your google sheet lookup, select the appropriate sheet and columns in the template and for the lookup value provide the data received in trigger step of this zap.

---

**Example Using Data From Your Question:**

ZAP_1
Trigger Step: New record created in Zoho
input: Zoho record data
Output: text_field = "001, 092, 011"

Action Step: Zapier Code Module:
input: text_field = "001, 092, 011"
Code Output:

```
lookup_values = ["001", "092", "011"]
# Iteration 1
requests.post(url="endpoint", json={"lookup": "001"})
# Iteration 2
requests.post(url="endpoint", json={"lookup" : "092"})
# Iteration 3
requests.post(url="endpoint", json={"lookup" : "011"})
```

ZAP_2 call 1
Trigger Step: Catch post request
Output: "001"

Action Step: Lookup spreadsheet row
Output: row values map

ZAP_2 call 2
Trigger Step: Catch post request
Output: "092"

Action Step: Lookup spreadsheet row
Output: row values map

ZAP_2 call 3
Trigger Step: Catch post request
Output: "011"

Action Step: Lookup spreadsheet row
Output: row values map

---

Unfortunately you may run into some issues if the row isn't found as subsequent steps that use data from the output of the google spreadsheet lookup call will not execute if it isn't found. Perhaps rather than setting a flag of 99999 for not found values you could instead set a flag for found values. Hopefully this has helped.